# Is there anyway to get MongoDB to work on Vercel Edge Serverless Functions

Tags: mongodb, next.js, vercel

I am experiencing long cold start times when making a new document using my API on Vercel Serverless Functions. To Speed up the request, I want to run the API on Vercel Edge Functions, but the edge runtime does not support the MongoDB official Node driver. Is there any way around this limitation/an unofficial driver I can use?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use Prisma ORM with MongoDB. Vercel's Edge functions do not support most of Node.js APIs (ref: https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/functions/edge-functions).

However, you can get around it by using their Prisma Data Proxy which allows you to interact with your database over HTTP. (ref: https://www.prisma.io/blog/database-access-on-the-edge-8F0t1s1BqOJE)

Answer (score 1):

There are some options.

1. Assuming you're hosting at MongoDB, you can use their [Atlas Data API](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/app-services/data-api/), which is an HTTP REST API.  You'll need to rewrite your database query / operation code to use `fetch()`.
2. I just created [mongodb-rest-relay](https://github.com/gadicc/mongodb-rest-relay), which is a drop-in-replacement (i.e. API compatible) for the `mongodb` driver, but relays each request over HTTP.  Currently the idea is to have the other end of the relay running on serverless infrastructure, but I might also add an option to use Atlas Data API as an endpoint.  I'm still experimenting with what works best.